# How do I Retrieve the data from Stored procedure without adding the newly added column in select statement?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I have added 3 columns as below in the table A

1. IsMobile -> bit -> not null
2. IMEINo nvarchar(MAX) null
3. TrackingNo nvarchar(MAX) null

But Previously It has 10 Columns. and Some Stored procedure is having select statement without these 3 new columns.

If I am binding the existing stored procedure returned list data with the Entity model , Then I am getting

{"The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'WMS.Data.Models.A'. A member of the type, 'IsMobile', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."}

In this case, I need to change the Entity model, not all stored procedures which is not having these columns.

Am I right ? If yes, Please help me to get the result.

Also How to bind the stored procedure returning data to the List  ?

[image: Added columns]

[image: Added models]

Note: Now the select statement in stored procedure is as below:

```
select distinct 
w.id,
w.dangerousGood,
w.Deleted ,w.Battery ,
w.AllocationDisposalID, 
w.warehouseNumber, 
w.customerSuiteId as customerSuiteId,
w.recievedDateToShopusa, 
w.invoiceAmount,
w.weightinLBS as weightinLBS,
w.weightinKGS as weightinKGS, 
w.widthinInch ,
w.depthinInch ,
w.heightinInch ,
w.PCS ,
w.volume ,
w.Created ,
w.WHUserName ,
w.IsConsolidated 
from A w
```

Here No new columns added in select statement.
But while binding to model in service method, I am getting the above error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  If you want the data to appear in the entities, then they do need to be added to the SELECT statement in the stored procedures.

Comment: Yes , I want the select statement with the existing columns alone .But not the newly added columns.

Comment: Here I don't want to disturb the existing Stored procedures with the new columns. Is it possible to access the old stored procedure to be bind in same model ? or else  need to be added to SELECT statement in the old stored procedures ?